# Can tone ethernet cable into patch panel but it's not working

Tags: ethernet, troubleshooting, cable

So we recently had to two major issues happen at a location.

1. We had a lightning strike hit the building
2. We updated switches after this lightning strike

Now one thing that was 'hit' was a SOHO router. After upgrading the server room, we realized that the port for this SOHO router no longer works. I toned the cable out fine but the replacement router (same make & model) isn't powering on. I've repunched the back of the port, I've tried different cables, etc still nothing. Short of rerunning this wire through the building is there anything else I can try? My thinking is that the lightning that hit the router also fried the ethernet cable.

Thanks.

Comment: What does the router not powering on have to do with the network cable? What do you mean you updated the switches? Do you mean that you replaced them? Have you tried plugging the router into a known good switch port and cable to confirm that it actually works?

Comment: @joeqwerty: I'm guessing it's a PoE-powered switch?

Comment: Psmears - bingo. joeqwerty - what I was getting at was I thought when the router was hit by lightning so was the ethernet cable, and as it turns out, my hunch was right.

Answer (score 10):

You can use a Fluke to test the pairs. That will tell you if the cable is bad; all the tone does is confirm that the two ends have electrical connectivity.

Comment: Have to concur with mfinni. Tone tells you end to end connectivity but says nothing about possible pair to pair shorts. Several people make microcontroller-powered CAT5 cable testers that test individual wires, some even at network speed; Fluke is one of them, of course.

Comment: Mfinni & TSC_Chazz,  thank you both! That was it! I have a cable tester kit. I connected and performed a test and sure enough, 3 blips out, it skips 4,5, & 6 and goes straight to 7 then 8. So the issue is with 4,5,6. Looks like I'll be running a new cable.

Comment: The bad news is that your existing cable is bad. The good news is that you already have a cable-puller in situ! Maybe pull two while you're at it, or pull a new cable and a pulling string at the same time.

Comment: @HeyHelpDeskGuy Start by using the eyeball - look at the front and rear of each jack for damage, melting, scorch marks, etc.   Then punch on a new jack and re-test before going to the effort of pulling new wire.

Comment: I wouldn't try reusing the cable. It's apparently been struck by lightning, or at least had enough voltage across it to melt some insulation internally. Even if it works when you replace the jacks, do you really trust it?

Comment: Hey everyone, so as it turns out there was another run through the conduit unused. I capped that with an Rj45 jack and tested and still nothing. I found another post on here suggesting to use a different toner and as luck would have it, I had that exact toner in my closet. It found a fault with pair 3, so I clipped off that RJ45 and installed a new one, and bam, we're good to go. Thanks everyone for all of your help.

Answer (score 5):

Since your talking about SOHO routers etc. I'm assuming that a tester from Fluke is way over budget to test one cable? And I've been in the same position where I've had to troubleshoot a cable without the budget for proper tools. So here comes a few things you can test.

I would start by connecting something I know works at the moment, (like a laptop) directly to the router on the port that you have problems with. When that is working I would then add one thing at a time to make sure that you find where the problem is. One tip here is to check 2 patch cables directly between the router and the laptop (or what ever you got to test with). So that you know that you have 2 working patches when you connect the laptop on the other end of the cable installed in the wall.

If you come to the conclusion that the cable installed in the wall is the fault. I would double or triple check both ends and make sure that the pairs are in the correct order.

If they are but you still do not get a working link over the cable. You can take a multi-meter and test each pair. (I'm assuming that you've already used one when you say that you have "toned" the cable?) You can make a cheap-mans network tester with a multi-meter and a cut off patch cable. I'm attaching a picture of each end of my own solution.

(I know that this cable doesn't have the normal white mixed colors like white-orange, white-green etc that you are used with in a network cable. But the brighter colors are the white-version of them.)

Cable End 1 (The one you test from):
[image: Cable end 1]

Cable End 2 (This one you put in the other end of the cable)
[image]

I would start by just using the first cable end and not the second end. This way you can test if there seems to be any shortcuts on the cable. So take your multi-meter and set it to use the summer function (so you get a tone out of it when you have a closed circuit). Now test every individual cable with each other. (Also make sure that you don't have anything at all connected to the other end!)

like this:

```
White-orange <-> Orange
White-orange <-> White-blue
White-orange <-> Blue
White-orange <-> White-green
White-orange <-> Green
White-orange <-> White-brown
White-orange <-> Brown
Orange <-> White-blue
Orange <-> Blue
Orange <-> White-green
Orange <-> Green
Orange <-> White-brown
Orange <-> Brown
White-blue <-> Blue
White-blue <-> White-green
White-blue <-> Green
White-blue <-> White-brown
White-blue <-> Brown
Blue <-> White-green
Blue <-> Green
Blue <-> White-brown
Blue <-> Brown
White-green <-> Green
White-green <-> White-brown
White-green <-> Brown
Green <-> White-brown
Green <-> Brown
White-brown <-> Brown
```

The order doesn't matter but you need to have a system to make sure that you test every combination.

If you do not get any tone during this test, you know that you don't have any shortcuts on the cable at least. Now you can connect the second end to the cable and do the test again. But this time you should only get a tone when you're testing the correct pairs. If you do get a tone on the pairs the cable should be good-to-go and if not you know which pair it is that isn't working and you could probably check the contacts again looking one extra time on those pairs.

You could also change the second end of the test patch, so that the non-working pair is split-up and connected to a cable of a working pair. This way you will be able to tell if the whole pair is lost or if one of the cables is working.

If you have at least 4 individual cables working, you could downgrade it to a 100Mbps link since that only uses 4 cables. Which usually shouldn't be a problem for a SOHO. But I don't know what you're using it for so you'll have to make this decision on your own.

Only the cables with a usage specified in the table below is used on a 100Mbps link. aka 1, 2, 3 & 6. Some of our ISP:s in my country used to ship cables with only 4 individual cables in them to save a few cents. So this is perfectly fine to do. But if you need a 1Gbps on this cable you'll have to change it...

TIA/EIA 568B wiring table (Note that the colors will change if you use TIA/EIA 568A):

```
Usage   Pin     Cable Color
TX+     1       White/Orange
TX-     2       Orange
RX+     3       White/Green
        4       Blue
        5       White/Blue
RX-     6       Green
        7       White/Brown
        8       Brown
```

You can read more about the cable pairs used in a 100Mbps cable [here](https://pinouts.ru/NetworkCables/Ethernet10BaseTStraightThru_pinout.shtml)

Comment: Fluke is high-end stuff and commands a high price.  There are integrated pair-testers which are much more affordable.  Definitely recommended for the non-pro installer or the hardware geek's toolbox.

Comment: @Criggie Do you have a link to one of those testers? Didn't seem to find much when i searched for "integrated pair-testers"... :)

Comment: Just as an example, https://www.gowifi.co.nz/hand-tools/rj45-pairtest.html  or https://www.amazon.com/Zoostliss-Network-Cable-Tester-Networking/dp/B06XZYXN63    They do depend on a minimum of two wires working somewhere in the run.   They essentially automate the methodical test you described.

Comment: Interesting! I have seen something similar earlier but don't think that they were this cheap back then. But maybe I was looking at the wrong places?